# Spring Boot as API Rest is not deserializing the entire object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

Im using Spring Boot as API Rest with VueJs on the frontend.

My models classes are:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
public class Habitante extends Persona {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[HM]$")
    private String sexo;

    @NotBlank
    private String nacionalidad;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Vivienda Vivienda;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Identificacion tarjetaIdentificacion;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String identificacion;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Solicitud implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9178661439383356177L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Past
    private Date fecha;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    private Habitante solicitante;

    private String justificacion;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[AM]$")
    @NotBlank
    private String tipo;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^(ACR|AIM|MV|MD|MRE)$")
    @NotBlank
    private String subtipo;

    // El estado puede ser pendiente (P), aceptada (A), rechazada (R) y cancelada (C)
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[ACRP]$")
    private String estado;

    // Sólo para menores de edad que lo quieran añadir o para personas con tarjeta identificativa
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(\\d{8}\\w)|(\\d{7}[XYZ])$")
    private String identificacion;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    private Identificacion tipoIdentificacion;

    private String nombre;

    private String primerApellido;

    private String segundoApellido;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    private Vivienda vivienda;

    @Past
    private Date fechaNacimiento;

    @Valid
    @OneToMany
    private List<Documento> documentos;
    
}
```

When I tried to send a new `Solicitud` using axios like this:

```
   const solicitud = {
        fecha: new Date(),
        solicitante: {
          id: props.userLogged.id
        },
        estado: 'P',
        justificacion: '',
        tipo: opcion.value,
        subtipo: subOpcion.value,
        nombre: nombre.value,
        primerApellido: primerApellido.value,
        segundoApellido: segundoApellido.value,
        fechaNacimiento: fechaNacimiento.value,
        tipoIdentificacion: { id: tipoIdentificacion },
        // identificacion: tIdentificacion,
        documentos: [],
      };
```

```
await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}solicitud/habitante/new`, solicitud);
```

```
@PostMapping(value = "/habitante/new")
    public Respuesta nuevaSolicitud(@RequestBody Solicitud solicitud){ ... }
```

On Spring, I dont get the entire `Habitante`object, only the `id`, the same thing happens with the property `vivienda` on another request, I get this:

[image: IntelIj debugger view]

Is there anyway to get the entire object on the controller?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as you are receiving this object from the network and not from your DB. I would query the repository with proper id to fill that field.

Comment: Hey @robert, thanks for answering! Thats what I though the first time, but I only have hope left after searching info for like 1h. And I would have to do that (querying to bbdd) when I need the entiry property. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked on the vue (client) side that the payload is actually populated?